# az network lb rule create: error: argument --resource-group/-g: expected one argument

Tags: azure-cli, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to create Azure loadbalancer rule using Cli however I get an error.
Here is what I have tried by looking at this Microsoft link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/lb/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-lb-rule-create

```
$ az --version
azure-cli                         2.0.80

$ az network lb rule create --backend-port 80 --frontend-port 80 --lb-name kubernetes --name ruleone --protocol Tcp --resource-group mylbresourcegroup --backend-pool-name kubernetes --frontend-ip-name 1-loadbalancer-ip-test --subscription mysubscriptionid
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: az network lb rule create: error: argument --resource-group/-g: expected one argument
```

Does anyone know what it is missing here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated:

I'm getting a new error after some testing:

```
$ az network lb rule create --backend-port 8000 --frontend-port 8000 --lb-name kubernetes --name ruleone --protocol Tcp --resource-group mc_resourcegroup-myrg_k8s-myrg_westeurope --backend-pool-name kubernetes --frontend-ip-name 1-6aa0497d-41fa-4789-ab5b-c3043775b036

Load Balancing Rules /subscriptions/mysubid/resourceGroups/mc_resourcegroup-myrg_k8s-myrg_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes/loadBalancingRules/ruleone must disable snat since same FrontendIPConfiguration /subscriptions/mysubid/resourceGroups/mc_resourcegroup-myrg_k8s-myrg_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes/frontendIPConfigurations/1-6aa0497d-41fa-4789-ab5b-c3043775b036 is referenced by Outbound Rules /subscriptions/mysubid/resourceGroups/mc_resourcegroup-myrg_k8s-myrg_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes/outboundRules/aksOutboundRule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test in my site and work well. This means that the command parameters are being parsed correctly. If this value has spaces make sure you use the value in double quotes `""`. And if you use the long parameter set `--resource-group $resourcegroupname`. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/3917).

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply can you check the updated part of my question as i'm getting a new error message

Comment: Set [`disableOutboundSnat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-rules-overview#disablesnat) on  load balancing rule.

Comment: Thanks it worked. One more question, when I set up Standard Loadbalancer for MultiAZ AKS, it creates two Backend Pool: "kubernetes" and "aksOutboundBackendPool". I'm wondering which one should I use for rules? Later I'm gonna assign this loadbalancer to my ingress Gateway (istio).

Comment: Glad to help you, you can accept this reply as answer. And post another case so that user can more clear to get your issue.